# Reversing words in a string with C++ iterators and reverse stl function

Tags: c++

throws segmentation fault. any idea what's the problem?
im trying to do the changes inplace without additional space.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    string s = "Hello world!";
    for(string::iterator it = s.begin();it!=s.end();it++){
        string::iterator st = it;
        while(st!=s.end() && *st!=' '){
            st++;
        }
        reverse(it,st);
        it = st;
    }
    cout<<s;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a DEBUG library that do validation and you should easily catch those error. Even without that, by tracing code with a debugger, you should be able to find the problem in not much time...

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the string, when the "!" will be read, the `st` iterator, will still be incremented, until it is at `end()`.

Then, in `it = st;`, you assign `end()` to `it`.

And then `it` will be incremented by the last statement in the for loop `it++`.

And this causes the trouble. It was already `end` and you increment it further.

Solution:

Do not increment `it` if it is already at `end()`.